# Displaying AJAX Call loading state in reactjs with flux

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I want to track loading, success and error state of Asynchronous Ajax request. My store is changing on loading, success and error action but react component is changing only when there is success or error. Therefore I am unable to detect loading state in react component.

Below is how my code looks like :

**Dispatcher**

```
var AppDispatcher = assign(new Dispatcher(), {
       handleServerAction: function(action) {
       var payload = {
         source: PayloadSources.SERVER_ACTION,
         action: action
       };
       this.dispatch(payload);
       }
    });
```

**Action Creator**

```
var ActionCreator = {
  loadData: function() {
  //Calling Synchronous Action          
     AppDispatcher.handleServerAction({actionType:ActionTypes.LOAD_DATA});

  //Calling Asynchronous Action
  ApiClient.getData(function(dataObj) {
  AppDispatcher.handleServerAction({actionType:ActionTypes.LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS, dataObj: dataObj});
   }.bind(this), function(error) {
  AppDispatcher.handleServerAction({actionType:ActionTypes.LOAD_DATA_FAIL, error: error});
    }.bind(this));
 }
};
```

**API CLIENT**

```
var ApiClient = {
/**
* @param success callback
* @param failure callback
*/
getData : function(success, failure){
  $.ajax({
     url : '/api/get-data',
     dataType: 'json',
     success : function(data){
        success(data);
     },
     error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        failure(errorThrown);
     }
  });
 }
};
```

**AppStore**

```
   var _state = {
           loading: false,
           error : null,
           dataObj: {}
         };

 function persistStoreData(loading, error, response) {
  _state.loading = loading;
  _state.error = error;
  _state.dataObj = response;
 }
var AppStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
   //writing only few important parts
   getState: function(){
      return _state;
   },
  dispatcherIndex: AppDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
  var action = payload.action;
  switch(action.actionType){
     case ActionTypes.LOAD_DATA:
        persistStoreData(true, null, {});
        break;
     case ActionTypes.LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS:
        persistStoreData(false, null, action.dataObj);
        break;
     case ActionTypes.LOAD_DATA_FAIL:
        persistStoreData(false, payload.action.error, {});
        break;
     default:
        return true;
  }
  AppStore.emitChange();
  return true; // No errors. Needed by promise in Flux Dispatcher.
)};
```

**React Component**

```
var AppComponent = React.createClass({

 getInitialState: function() {
   return AppStore.getState();
 },

 componentDidMount: function() {
   ActionCreator.loadData();//Invoking Action, loading data
   AppStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
 },

 componentWillUnmount: function() {
   AppStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
 },

 render: function(){
    <div className="panel-body">
         {this.state.error ? "Error loading data" : null}
         {this.state.loading ? 'Loading...': null}
         {this.state.dataObj?'Success': null}
    </div>
 }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code for your store? Especially `persistStoreData ` and `getState` functions.

Comment: @nilgun I added both functions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution, I found to solve this problem is that, assuming the loading state is true when there in no data in state and error state is false.

So my render method in view component looks like :-

```
  render: function { 
   return{
    (<div>
      {Util.isEmpty(this.state.data) && !(this.state.error) ? 'Loading...': null}
    </div>);
   }
```